# editable cell in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement editable cell in tableview, just like what is available in new contact screen in iphone and ipod
Right now I have two labels in a cell, one of which will remain same all the time and the other one will be editable. Do I need to change this label to textfield.

one more thing I also want that when i click one such cell it should pop a picker view and and set the picerview value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Umang in order to make your `UITableView` cells editable I suggest you to give `UITextField` to your cell....for more help how to do it take help from already asked [How to make tableviewcell text editable on touch in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677532/how-to-make-tableviewcell-text-editable-on-touch-in-iphone-sdk/4677748#4677748)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should add a UITextField to the cell if you want to editable. **but**
from your question i understand that you want to set a piker value to the cell label.
**in this case you don't need to change the cell.**

you should add the pop the picker in the didSelectRow method, and change the cell label to its result.

if you dont know how just ask and i will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you will need to change it to a textfield. UILabel is non-editable by design.